# Rotate the camera around an object using the Buttons in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, orthographic

I have STL model loaded in my scene.

I want to show Left, Right, Top, Bottom and Front, Back side of my model by rotating camera.
I want exactly like [Reference](https://docs.cadexchanger.com/web-toolkit/getting-started-examples-3d-viewer.html) this. Free movement of camera and set different views. another reference [ThreeJS Reference Example](http://192.241.199.119:8080/dev/viewCube/) but this code is not Open Source.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;
let controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {


    let aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    let frustumSize = 2;

    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(frustumSize * aspectRatio / -2,
        frustumSize * aspectRatio / 2,
        frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / -2,
        -50,
        50);
    camera.position.z = 1;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xD3D3D3);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    let frontlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x808080, .3);
    scene.add(frontlight);


    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.7);
    scene.add(ambientLight);


    createControls();
    loadSTL();
}

function createControls() {
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
}


window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

    switch (event.keyCode) {


        case 49: //Top View
            // setView(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1));
            setView(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            break;

        case 50: //Bottom View
            setView(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1), new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI, 0, 0));

            break;

        case 51: //Left View
            setView(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI / 2, (-Math.PI / 2), 0));
            break;

        case 52: //Right View
            setView(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, 0));
            break;

        case 53: //Front View
            setView(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-(Math.PI / 2), 0, Math.PI));
            break;

        case 54: //Back View
            setView(new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0), new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0));

            break;
    }

});

function setView(offSetFactor, axisAngle) {
    const offsetUnit = camera.position.length();
    const offSet = new THREE.Vector3(offsetUnit * offSetFactor.x,
        offsetUnit * offSetFactor.y,
        offsetUnit * offSetFactor.z);

    const center = new THREE.Vector3();
    const finishPos = center.add(offSet);

    const euler = new THREE.Euler(axisAngle.x, axisAngle.y, axisAngle.z);
    const finishQuaterion = new THREE.Quaternion().copy(camera.quaternion).setFromEuler(euler);

    /*  let boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(scene);
     let boxCenter = new THREE.Vector3();
     boundingBox.getCenter(boxCenter); */


    const duration = 400;
    const start = performance.now();
    const maxAlpha = 1;

    function loop() {
        const now = performance.now();
        const delta = now - start;
        const alpha = Math.min(delta / duration, maxAlpha);
        camera.position.lerp(finishPos, alpha);
        controls.update();

        camera.quaternion.slerp(finishQuaterion, alpha);
        camera.up.set(0, 1, 0);
        controls.update();

        if (alpha !== maxAlpha)
            return requestAnimationFrame(loop)
        /* camera.lookAt(boxCenter);
                 controls.target.set(boxCenter.x,boxCenter.y,boxCenter.z);
         */
    }

    loop();
}

function loadSTL() {
    let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffdead,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    var stlLoader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    stlLoader.load('https://cdn.glitch.global/3c40c6ea-d629-4a1b-8129-bd041944a124/monkey.stl?v=1659713089046',
        function(geometry) {

            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                color: 0xff5533
            });
            var meshSTL = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            scene.add(meshSTL);
            fitToScreen(scene, camera, controls);

        });
}

function fitToScreen(group, camera, controls) {
    let boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(group);
    let distance = boundingBox.min.distanceTo(boundingBox.max) * 0.1;
    let boxCenter = new THREE.Vector3();
    boundingBox.getCenter(boxCenter);

    camera.position.set(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, distance);
    camera.lookAt(boxCenter);
    controls.target.set(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Here is  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thehiddenany/m5eyfwob/52/) link what I implemented so far use 1 to 6 keys to change Views. In am not able to set left, right and front view properly.

I am using Trackball controls and orthographic camera this is my need I cannot change camera and controls. There is one library [Gizmo Library](https://github.com/fennec-hub/ThreeOrbitControlsGizmo) but this library work specifically for orbit controls

I want to rotate camera by clicking on button. I know once I know how to rotate camera properly I can hook up UI with this but just FYI. I will keep Six buttons to set this views.

Here is what I tried So far

Comment: In testing the JSFiddle, all the views appear to work normally for me. The only issue I see is the camera animating into the view and then abruptly reorienting the model, probably to avoid gimbal lock. The correct side is still shown, though.

Comment: @mayacoda Yes Some views are normal but if you check left and right view they are not correct and also front view these three views are not correct. so what can you suggest needs to improve to have all views correct.